# Creating GET/POST services Ocsigen

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen, ocaml-lwt

I am building a app using `Ocsigen`, this app will not be connected to a database and the goal is to copy the content from the main website to here. (i am using curl to do Get requests)

So my problem here is, I am trying to do a "log in" with a user, and I want to build a service that saves to my code the `username` and the `password` that is introduced by the user. Then I could use the `username` and the `password` to do the GET request to the main website.

My problem it's only one, I have tried a lot of ways to build a service that saves this two strings but I can't figure out a way.

I did a lot of diferent tries and my last one I did something like the following:

```
let save_data =
  Eliom_registration.Action.create
    ~meth:
      (Eliom_service.Post
         (Eliom_parameter.unit,
          Eliom_parameter.string "username"))
    ~path:Eliom_service.No_path
    (fun () username -> username)
```

Based on an example that Ocsigen has on their website but I doesn't work...

I created a form that is successfully executing the services I created, but the service is never doing what I need.

Sorry if I explained badly the situation... Is any idea how to solve this problem? I am going in the wrong way?

Thnx!

PS: I have also tried to edit the Os_services.connect_service form the Ocsigen-Start src folder, and I guess that I have to do a Post Service to this case, but again I failed to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Eliom_reference, that is if you wish to keep the information stored for later.

https://ocsigen.org/eliom/api/server/Eliom_reference

I'm a little bit rusty when it comes to Eliom but it would look like this:

```
let current_username : string option Eliom_reference.eref =
  Eliom_reference.eref ~scope:Eliom_common.default_process_scope None

let save_data = Eliom_registration.Action.create
  ~meth:(Eliom_service.Post
           (Eliom_parameter.unit,
            Eliom_parameter.string "username"))
  ~path:(Eliom_service.No_path)
  (fun () username -> Eliom_reference.set current_username (Some username))
```

Comment: it Helps!! Thanks you